# when trying to choose random file, i get "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.png'"

Tags: python

i tried to make a variable that chooses a random file, but the program thinks that its not there, even though i can see it through my explorer. i tried using the full directory (D:/folder/media/images) yet i still get the same error. i dont know what to do

```
videodir = os.listdir("media/videos")
imagedir = os.listdir("media/images")

random1 = open(random.choice(videodir))
random2 = open(random.choice(imagedir))
random3 = open(random.choice(imagedir))
```

Comment: Did you look to see what is in `videodir`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.listdir` returns filenames not the full path. You'll need to prepend your folder path like so:

```
random1 = open("media/videos/" + random.choice(videodir))
```

Comment: it works you just have to add another / at the end of "media/videos" thank you